# String contains - ignore case

Tags: java, string, contains, case-insensitive

Is it possible to determine if a String `str1="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"` contains a string pattern `strptrn="gHi"`? I wanted to know if that's possible when the characters are case insensitive. If so, how?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can use

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(CharSequence str,
                                     CharSequence searchStr);
```

> Checks if CharSequence contains a search CharSequence irrespective of
>   case, handling null. Case-insensitivity is defined as by
>   String.equalsIgnoreCase(String).
>
> A null CharSequence will return false.

This one will be better than regex as **regex is always expensive** in terms of performance.

For official doc, refer to : [StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

**Update :**

If you are among the ones who

- don't want to use Apache commons library
- don't want to go with the expensive `regex/Pattern` based solutions,
- don't want to create additional string object by using `toLowerCase`,

you can implement your own custom `containsIgnoreCase` using [java.lang.String.regionMatches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches-boolean-int-java.lang.String-int-int-)

```
public boolean regionMatches(boolean ignoreCase,
                             int toffset,
                             String other,
                             int ooffset,
                             int len)
```

`ignoreCase` : if true, ignores case when comparing characters.

```
public static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String str, String searchStr)     {
    if(str == null || searchStr == null) return false;

    final int length = searchStr.length();
    if (length == 0)
        return true;

    for (int i = str.length() - length; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str.regionMatches(true, i, searchStr, 0, length))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Plenty of other nice stuff in there, such as indexOfIgnoreCase...

Comment: That method makes an assumption that the length of the matched part of the haystack will be the same number of UTF-16 code units as the length of the needle. So if you're searching for "ß" and the string contains "SS", it won't find a match, even though these two strings are identical if you ignore the case (in German locale, and of course you do have to set the locale whenever doing this sort of thing.)

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils this package not available in android

Answer (score 272):

If you won't go with regex:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP".toLowerCase().contains("gHi".toLowerCase())
```

Comment: While this could be an answer, I don't think it's a good solution on big `String`s

Comment: This doesn't work in the wide world of unicode - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996550/372926

Comment: Like `if (file.getName().toLowerCase()
      .contains(editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase())) `

Comment: its true as suggested,  regex would always be expensive.

Comment: @SamStephens , toLowerCase() of unicode will work in java7+. in your link you can see comments for the reasons..

Comment: It lowercases correctly. But that doesn't mean this comparison works for all cultures. See http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding. They recommend either specifying a culture, or explicitly using a case insentive compare function such as containsIgnoreCase shown above.

Answer (score 23):

You can use java.util.regex.Pattern with the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag for case insensitive matching:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(strptrn), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(str1).find();
```

Comment: take a look at the previous answer @SamStephens wrote http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996550/372926 : you must specify both CASE_INSENSITIVE and UNICODE_CASE, and you still will not get the right values, because while Java uses full casemapping, it uses only simple casefolding. This is a problem."

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String original = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ";
    String tobeChecked = "GHi";

    System.out.println(containsString(original, tobeChecked, true));        
    System.out.println(containsString(original, tobeChecked, false));

}

public static boolean containsString(String original, String tobeChecked, boolean caseSensitive)
{
    if (caseSensitive)
    {
        return original.contains(tobeChecked);

    }
    else
    {
        return original.toLowerCase().contains(tobeChecked.toLowerCase());
    }

}
```

Comment: Pass true as third parameter if you want value to be checked in case sensitive manner and pass false if you want value to be checked in case insensitive manner.

Answer (score 1):

An optimized Imran Tariq's version

```
Pattern.compile(strptrn, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE + Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(str1).find();
```

Pattern.quote(strptrn) always returns "\Q" + s + "\E" even if there is nothing to quote, concatination spoils performance.

Comment: You should use the bitwise | operator instead of the addition operator.