# Ignore case for 'contains' for a string in Java

Tags: java, string

Consider:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "AbcD";

    System.out.println(s.contains("ABCD"));
    System.out.println(s.contains("AbcD"));
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

I need the result to be true in both cases regardless of the case. Is it possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018478/string-contains-ignore-case

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to convert both the strings to the same case before using `contains`

```
s.toLowerCase().contains("ABCD".toLowerCase());
```

Comment: This won't necessarily work, since case convertion is locale specific. `"i".toLowerCase().contains("I".toLowerCase())` may e.g. return false.

Comment: @jarnbjo I tested it in my location(middle east), US and English but that's not true. what location do you mean?

Comment: @David Any locale with deviating upper/lower-case rules won't work as expected. For Turkish, `"I".toLowerCase();` will e.g. return `"ı"` and not `"i"`.

Answer (score 30):

You could use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(String, String)`

`StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(s, "ABCD")` returns true

Apache documentation [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: I think this has the best answer out of all. Much more convenient. @PSR, I think you should mark this as answer if this really helps.

Answer (score 5):

Not that it would be particularly efficient but you could use a `Pattern` matcher to make a case-insensitive match:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
pattern.matcher("ABCD").find();
pattern.matcher("AbcD").find();
```

Also note that it won't magically solve the locale issue but it will handle it differently than `toLowercase(Locale)`, with the conjunction of the `Pattern.UNICODE_CASE` flag, it may be able to handle all locales at once.

Comment: A bit inefficient to use RegEx for this :)

Comment: @phloc The problem of using `toLowerCase()` is that the result depends on the current locale.

Comment: That's why I suggested toLowercase(Locale.US) - or whatever locale you want.

Comment: what if your string contains special chars for example s= "example\". In this case this pattern matcher will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Using "toLowercase" helps:

```
System.out.println(s.toLowercase(Locale.US).contains("ABCD".toLowercase (Locale.US)));
```

(of course you could also use toUppercase instead)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `toLowerCase`. Something like this:

```
s.toLowerCase().contains("aBcd".toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It will return `0` if the string matched...

```
System.out.println(s.compareToIgnoreCase("aBcD"));
```

It will work fine.

Comment: contains and compare are two different things

Comment: @BuSaeed- obviously.