# Make condition ignore capslock?

Tags: java, android

How to make condition ignore capslock? I want to chang the:

> if ( **Name.contains** ( layout.txtName.getText ().toString () ) )

and make it ignore the caps.

```
case R.id.Contane:
            if (Name.contains(layout.txtName.getText().toString()))
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                alert.setTitle("this is the first resulet for the name that you typed");

                alert.setMessage("The contact "+Name+" was found in this phone... yaah");

                alert.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                    {


                    }

                });
                alert.show();
                Found = true;
                break;
```

Comment: what do you mean by ignore capslock? Do you mean to check it with case-insensitivity?

Comment: Are you looking for `.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String contains - ignore case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018478/string-contains-ignore-case)

Comment: no imean like if ihave contact and hes name is:"Asaf"
so ican type in the edittext: "asaf" and it will find the contact: "Asaf"

Comment: Also I don't think you need to use `toString()` in a method that I think return a `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  `toLowerCase()`

```
if ( Name.toLowerCase().contains ( layout.txtName.getText ().toString ().toLowerCase()))
```

*Example:*

```
if("Abc".toLowerCase().contains("a".toLowerCase()))
    System.out.print("Success");
```

*Output:*

```
Success
```

Comment: remember: Name.toLowerCase().contains

Answer (score 2):

There is a method in the String library called equalsIgnoreCase(), with this you can ignore caps lock.

You also have the method toLowerCase() which turns caps locks to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (Name.toLowerCase().contains(layout.txtName.getText().toString().toLowerCase()))
```

Unfortunately there is no `containsIgnoreCase` method.

Also, but off-topic you might want to:

- Check for nulls
- Use [Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and rename `Name` to `name`