# How to convert contains to equals.ignorecase?

Tags: java, string, contains

I am reading a text file into my program, and having the user search for a string. How can I make this so its case-insensitive? Here is a snippet of my code:

```
while (str1.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = str1.nextLine();
    line = line.replace(";", " ");
    if(line.contains(Val))
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    } 

}
```

`Val` is the string variable. It is the string that the user entered, and the string that, if found in the text file, will print out on the line. But I need it to be case-insensitive. For some reason when I use `equals.IgnoreCase` it doesn't work.

Comment: [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) has no dot

Comment: Other options where you can avoid creating intermediate strings: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/is-the-contains-method-in-java-lang-string-case-sensitive) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018478/string-contains-ignore-case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this scenario, make everything a unified case, and compare.

```
if (line.toLowerCase().contains(Val.toLowerCase())) {
    // logic
}
```

There are limitations on what [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) can do.  It only checks `CharSequences` and does so in a case-sensitive fashion.  By introducing a common case, this eliminates the case sensitivity issue.

Comment: As a note to OP: please don't call `Val.toLowerCase()` in the loop. Create an own variable which holds the "converted" String outside that loop and use that instead.

Comment: @Tom On the one hand, I agree. On the other hand, this may be premature optimisation, leading to the unnecessary creation of a new variable and not being faster at all.

Comment: @MrLister Since `toLowerCase` returns a new String if `Val` isn't already in lowercase it is faster*. How much faster, on the other hand, depends on the size of the file. (*) HotSpot may replaces that call, but I wouldn't wait for that or rely on that.

Comment: ...In this simplistic scenario, why are you worried about speed?  If this operation were done several million times over the normal course of its operations, I'd start worrying about its performance, but *here*?  I don't see any reason to fret about it @Tom.

Comment: @Makoto I'm more worried about the unnecessary multiple creation of equal Strings. The (relatively) better performace is a positive side effect.