# Ignore case for a string in scala

Tags: scala, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Consider:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val s:String = "AbcD"

    println(s.contains("ABCD"))
    println(s.contains("AbcD"))

  }
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

I need the result to be true in both cases regardless of the case. Is it possible?

Comment: See `String.equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018478/string-contains-ignore-case

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you really need `contains` use

```
s.toLowerCase.contains("abcd")
```

But most likely you are looking for

```
s.equalsIgnoreCase("abcd")
```

Comment: just pointing out that if the argument to `contains` is dynamic, they would need to call `toLowerCase` on that as well to be case insensitive all around.

Answer (score 2):

with Regex

```
println(s.matches("(?i:.*" + "ABCD" + ".*)"))
```