# How to find string in another string and also ignoring lower / uppercase?

Tags: java

I need to define is my query is DDL or DML. To do this i need to try to find out part of strings like "create" "update" etc. in another string (my query).

My strings:

```
"CreATE table test (id number);"
"sElECT * from user;"
"ALTER table;"
```

**Can someone tell me how to return true if string contains "create / select / alter" and also ignore lower and uppercase?**
I tried that:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(query), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("CREATE").find())
```

but it sometimes works and sometimes not, i think this is bad way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String contains - ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018478/string-contains-ignore-case)

Comment: Should be  `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("create"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(query).find())`

Comment: If you want check that it contains any of the create / select / alter - 
    `Stream.of("create", "select" ,"alter").anyMatch(myString.toLowerCase()::contains);`

Comment: Wow, in fact, I had it the opposite way it should be. Thanks J Anand Boss :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use String class methods

```
"CreATE table test (id number);".toLowerCase().contains("create")
```