# Get Substring from a String in Java

Tags: java, string

I have the following text:

> ...,Niedersachsen,NOT IN CHARGE SINCE: 03.2009, CATEGORY:...,

Now I want to extract the date after `NOT IN CHARGE SINCE:` until the comma.
So i need only `03.2009` as result in my substring.

So how can I handle that?

```
String substr = "not in charge since:";
String before = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(substr));
String after = s.substring(s.indexOf(substr),s.lastIndexOf(","));
```

**EDIT**

```
for (String s : split) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    if (s.contains("ex peps")) {
        String substr = "not in charge since:";
        String before = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(substr));
        String after = s.substring(s.indexOf(substr), s.lastIndexOf(","));

        System.out.println(before);
        System.out.println(after);
        System.out.println("PEP!!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Line ok");
    }
}
```

But that is not the result I want.

Comment: `String.substring` is case-sensitive, so in your example, `substr` won't be found in `s`. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126227/indexof-case-sensitive)

Comment: Have edit my post

Comment: @Captai-N you should probably consider a regex. It would be much more efficient, and readable.

Comment: Your issue is using `lastIndexOf(",")`. If the string after `SINCE` contains more than one `,`, it won't work. You should get the first index of `,` in the substring after `SINCE`

Comment: @Shashwat Well. If there are no other colons in that string, then a simple `indexOf(':')` will beat *any* regex regarding performance.

Comment: You say that is not the result you want. Can you show *exactly* what is the result you get and which is the one you want?

Comment: @GhostCat well, the OP has `...` as the start of the String, so I implied there could be any character there. If not, you're probably correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Patterns for example :

```
String str = "Niedersachsen,NOT IN CHARGE SINCE: 03.2009, CATEGORY";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
03.2009
```

---

**Note :** if you want to get similar dates in all your String you can use `while` instead of `if`.

---

**Edit**

Or you can use :

```
String str = "Niedersachsen,NOT IN CHARGE SINCE: 03.03.2009, CATEGORY";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("SINCE:(.*?)\\,");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it works as far. But the date can also be a full date format for example 01.03.20009

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:` to separate the `String` s.

```
String substr = "NOT IN CHARGE SINCE:";
String before = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(substr)+1);
String after = s.substring(s.indexOf(':')+1, s.lastIndexOf(','));
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course, regular expressions give you more ways to do searching/matching, but assuming that the ":" is the key thing you are looking for (and it shows up **exactly** once in that position) then:

```
s.substring(s.indexOf(':')+1, s.lastIndexOf(',')).trim();
```

is the "most simple" and "least overhead" way of fetching that substring.

Hint: as you are searching for a single character, use a character as search pattern; not a string!

Comment: Makes sense ... but his question isnt really clear. Does he want the number, or a string with the trailing space ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a more generic usecase and you know the structure of the text to be matched well you might profit from using regular expressions:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*NOT IN CHARGE SINCE: \([0-9.]*\),");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to solve your problem is to use Regex to match Every group Between : and ,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=:)(.*?)(?=,)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a pattern for it. Try this as a simple regex starting point, and feel free to improvise on it:

```
String s = "...,Niedersachsen,NOT IN CHARGE SINCE: 03.2009, CATEGORY:....,";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*NOT IN CHARGE SINCE: ([\\d\\.]*).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

That should get you whatever group of digits you received as date.